# Scanf input carries over to next scanf

Tags: c, input, scanf

I have a code here which has some unwanted behaviour when inputting strings with spaces. eg `print illegal_argument`. When an input with multiple words comes in I would like it to only register the first word.

What currently happens is:

```
christian@oblig2 $ print 0
Enter router ID for information > ID: 0, flag: f7, model_length: 13, model: D-Link y6000
```

It registers the first `print` for the comparison in the command-loop. But instead of `scanf` prompting the user for the next input, it instead ignores that and takes the second word/number input by the user from the previous `scanf`.

What I want to happen is:

```
christian@oblig2 $ print 0
Enter router ID for information > 0
ID: 0, flag: f7, model_length: 13, model: D-link y6000.
```

Everything works as intended otherwise, but I wonder if there's a simpler way to do this. I've tried using Strtok, without much luck.

```
char input[256];
printf("%s@oblig2 $ ", getenv("USER"));
scanf("%s", input);

if(strcmp(input, "print") == 0) {
    print();
}
```

The above code is how I get input from the user.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: When you want the whole input line, don't use `scanf`, use `fgets` instead.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Trying `fgets(input, 256, stdin)` doesn't work, unless I'm doing something wrong. Trying `$ print` produces `: command not found.`.

Comment: @Christian S `fgets(input, 256, stdin)` works.  Other things in code need to change too.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input

Answer (score 2):

After the `scanf()` takes the first input value, it leaves the rest in the input stream. Try this to discard the remaining characters:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
    continue;             // discard remaining characters
```

If you put these lines before the next read from `stdin`, the extra characters won't corrupt your input.

Comment: Note: On end-of-file `while (getch() != '\n')` is an infinite loop.

Comment: True @chux, but a line of user input from the terminal always ends with a '\n', doesn't it?

Comment: "input from the terminal always ends with a '\n'," --> not _always_.  The behavior is implementation specific.

Comment: OK, @chux-- edited the above code to handle such cases.

Comment: `getch` is not a standard function.  Did you mean `getc`?